# RequestParam annotation doesn't work with POST

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/member/uploadExternalImage",
            "/member/uploadExternalImage" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("url") String url,
            Principal principal) throws IOException {
        File file = restTemplate.getForObject("url", File.class);
        file.toString();
        return null;
    }
```

And I have the following ajax:

```
      $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadExternalImage',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            success: function () {

            },
            complete:function(){
                $.fancybox.hideLoading();
            },

            // Form data
            data: {url: files[0].link},

            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
       });
```

in spring log I see that

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'url' is not present
```

if I change ajax method with GET:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'uploadExternalImage?url=123',  //Server script to process data
                type: 'POST',
                success: function () {

                },
                complete:function(){
                    $.fancybox.hideLoading();
                },
                error: function (data) {

                },

                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
           });
```

it works fine

How does to configure spring correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Http `POST` is capable of being used for request parameters on request body. But you are trying to use it on a different way.

Try this:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "uploadExternalImage?url=BLABLA",
                data: text,
                success: function (data) {
                    //
                }
            });
```

If you want it on request body then use `@RequestBody`

Comment: Yes, this works. But I want to pass data inside body

Comment: It is wprking but In controller I see **[object Object]**